# Write a method to print a string with words reversed, without the use of any standard functions

Tags: java, reverse, words

I was asked this in a technical interview. I have no idea whatsoever please please help me.

it goes in infinite loop. I just cant find the correct logic.
not once, but twice i came across this kind of a question, so please help

```
public static int numberOfCharsInString(String sentence) 
{

    int numberOfChars = 0,i=0;

    while (!sentence.equals("")) 
    {
        sentence = sentence.substring(1);
        ++numberOfChars;
    }
        return numberOfChars;
}
public static void reverseSequenceOfWords(String inp)
{
    int len=numberOfCharsInString(inp);
    char[] in=inp.toCharArray();
    int i=0;
    for(i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(in[i]==' ')
        {
            while(!in.equals("")||in.equals(" "))
            {
                System.out.print(in[i]+" ");
            }
        }
        else if(in[i]=='\0')
        {
            break;
        }

    }

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    int length=0;
    String inpstring = "";
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);
    try
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a string to reverse:");
        inpstring = reader.readLine();
        length=numberOfCharsInString(inpstring);
        System.out.println("Number of Characters: "+length);
        reverseSequenceOfWords(inpstring);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
            {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }       
}
```

Comment: Split the string into an array based on space delimiter and print the array in reverse

Comment: @blank Not very helpful unless you explain how to do that *without* using `String.split` or any other "standard function".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik then the question becomes how to split a string without split

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik But then again, everything you do with a `String` to reverse it will at some point use a "standard function" ;)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Was just going to ask OP about that :) There must be a defined minimal set of allowed methods. But you can guess what  those would be: `charAt` is one, `System.out.print` another.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array = "Are you crazy".split(" ");
for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
   System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: "without the use of any standard functions"

Comment: if ( i > 0 ) { print " "; } then print the word.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the .split() is the standard function here.

Comment: @Solace: Doh! Of course.

Comment: Ok, so `String.toCharArray()` is also a standard function. How do you do it without that huh? ;)

Comment: @LanceJava: Yes, but there's a hierarchy. I would assume `System.out.print` would be fine, but `String#split` wouldn't be. Just a feel. I don't know where `toCharArray` would be on that spectrum, compared to `charAt` for instance.

Comment: @LanceJava You can do very well without `toCharArray`. All you need is  `charAt`.

Comment: Ok, so you'd need `String.length()` and `String.charAt()`. Aren't these standard functions too?

Comment: I think a function is a method that performs some form of task...like Arrays.sort(). length() and charAt() seem to more like accessors.

Comment: @LanceJava - See. By "not using standard functions" , the OP means  - "don't use functions that make the problem very simple. length, toCharArray() etc are allowed because they don't directly affect the problem's complexity but split() will reduce the problem's complexity substantially."

Answer (score 0):

Brute forced this so hard lol

```
 public static void main (String args[]){       
    String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    input+=" ";
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    int start = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++){
        if(input.charAt(i)==' '){
            String toAdd="";
            for(int r=start; r<i; r++){
                toAdd+=input.charAt(r);
            }
            words.add(toAdd);
            start = i+1;
        }
    }

    for(int i=words.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
        System.out.print(words.get(i)+" ");
    }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used `String.length()` and `String.substring()`and `String.charAt()` - I hope that is allowed.

```
private static class Word {

    private final String message;
    private final int start;
    private final int end;

    public Word(String message, int start, int end) {
        this.message = message;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return message.substring(start, end);
    }
}

private Word[] split(String message) {
    // Split it into words - there cannot be more words than characters in the message.
    int[] spaces = new int[message.length()];
    // How many words.
    int nWords = 0;
    // Pretend there's a space at the start.
    spaces[0] = -1;
    // Walk the message.
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        if (message.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            spaces[++nWords] = i;
        }
    }
    // Record the final position.
    spaces[++nWords] = message.length();
    // Build the word array.
    Word[] words = new Word[nWords];
    for (int i = 0; i < nWords; i++) {
        words[i] = new Word(message, spaces[i] + 1, spaces[i + 1]);
    }
    return words;
}

private String reverse(String message) {
    Word[] split = split(message);
    String reversed = "";
    for ( int i = split.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed += split[i].toString();
        if ( i > 0 ) {
            reversed += " ";
        }
    }
    return reversed;
}

public void test() {
    String message = "Hello how are you today?";
    System.out.println(reverse(message));
}
```

prints

```
today? you are how Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Much more minimal but less useful. Only uses `length`, `charAt` and `substring` again:

```
public void printWordsReversed(String message) {
    int end = message.length();
    for ( int i = end - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ( message.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            System.out.print(message.substring(i+1, end)+" ");
            end = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(message.substring(0, end));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The only function i'm still using is the IndexOf function, but that is not that hard to create for yourself.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sentence = "are you cracy";

    int length = Program.StringLength(sentence);

    int currentpos = 0;

    List<string> wordList = new List<string>();

    int wordCount = 0;
    while (currentpos < length)
    {
        // find the next space
        int spacepos = sentence.IndexOf(' ', currentpos);

        string word;

        if (spacepos < 0)
        {
            // end of string reached.
            word = sentence.Substring(currentpos, length - currentpos);
            wordList.Add(word);
            wordCount++;

            // no need to continue.
            break;
        }

        word = sentence.Substring(currentpos, spacepos - currentpos);
        wordList.Add(word);
        wordCount++;

        currentpos = spacepos + 1;
    }

    // display
    for (int i = wordList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // after first word is display, add spaces to the output
        if (i < wordList.Count - 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }

        // display word
        Console.WriteLine(wordList[i]);
    }
}

public static int StringLength(String sentence)
{
    int numberOfChars = 0;

    while (!sentence.Equals(""))
    {
        sentence = sentence.Substring(1);
        ++numberOfChars;
    }

    return numberOfChars;
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: c#, btw the substring is also a in-system function.

Comment: This is a java question

Comment: So? Should I also perform the entire interview for him? I give him a working solution and it doesn't matter in what language I give it, because a reasonable coder can translate it with ease.